# how do I download all entries from a livejournal blog?

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to download a complete livejournal blog, to be able to view it exactly as it looks online, offline. So all images that are linked to etc should all be downloaded and re-linked too.

The pages start at runawaytoday.livejournal.com/295820.html and end at 453506.html, and the incrementation is not even.

I've tried:

```
wget --wait=2 --limit-rate=400K -r -k -p -U Mozilla http://runawaytoday.livejournal.com/
```

which stops because of a robots.txt file

I tried to iterate through the pages but can't get it right:

```
wget -p -k ${http://runawaytoday.livejournal.com/}{295820..453506}.html
```

gives me "-bash: /usr/local/bin/wget: Argument list too long"

any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm on osx 10.9 with bash version 3.2.53

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the robots.txt (although this might not be the best idea) http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#line-230

So your command might look like: 
`wget -e robots=off --random-wait -U Mozilla --mirror -p --convert-links http://runawaytoday.livejournal.com/`

`--random-wait` picks a random time between 0.5 and 2 seconds to wait.